# stop 'Cannot be Negative" error when deleting text from EditText in android

Tags: c#, android, backspace, xamarin.android

Wasn't sure what to title this as and couldn't find anything regarding my particular problem.

i have the following snippet of code which allows me to backspace text entered into an `EditText` box.

```
btnClear.Click += delegate {
            nView.Text = nView.Text.Remove(nView.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        };
```

When i eventually clear the `EditText` box and click once more (going to -1 characters), the app crashes and says 'Cannot Be Negative'.

I need some kind of prevention to stop users from deleting too many characters and crashing the app.

What do i implement? I'm using C# as my coding language too people. Thanks.

Comment: Next time you encounter such an error, think about what information you have available. In this instance you for your convenience have the length of the string in the `EditText` available to you. Now the error tells you that what you are trying to remove something that is negative or in other words something that is less than 0. Now that you know that think about how to avoid that. In programming languages you have cool stuff like if statements, where you can control the code flow. Use that along with the information you know.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks again, you're slowly becoming my personal android tutor - brilliant information :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add an "if":

```
btnClear.Click += delegate {
    if (nView.Text.Length > 0)
        nView.Text = nView.Text.Remove(nView.Text.Length - 1, 1);
};
```